# Colab Failed (How) to import files from git

Tags: python, github, python-import, google-colaboratory

I am new to using Colab and cannot find anything to make it work. Could anybody help me fix it or share a solution?

```
!git clone https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist.git
!pip install pycuda
!pip install scikit-cuda
```

with

```
from eucl_dist.gpu_dist import dist as gdist
```

```
>ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3a47b1a9783d> in <module>()  
----> 1 from eucl_dist.gpu_dist import dist as gdist  

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eucl_dist.gpu_dist'
```

or

```
from eucl_dist.eucl_dist.gpu_dist import dist as gdist
```

```
>ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b8b89f98116e> in <module>()  
    ----> 1 from eucl_dist.eucl_dist.gpu_dist import dist as gdist
    /content/eucl_dist/eucl_dist/gpu_dist.py in <module>()  
          3 import skcuda.linalg as culinalg  
          4 import skcuda.misc as misc  
    ----> 5 from eucl_dist.gpu_supp import sq_sums, squared_sum, convert_f32  
          6   
          7 culinalg.init()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eucl_dist.gpu_supp'
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You just cloned the repo. You need to change directory to "eucl_dist" and then run the other pip commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is subfolder named 'eucl_dist' under 'eucl_dist' again.

So, you have to access './eucl_dist/eucl_dist/gpu_dist'

Try this one.

```
%cd eucl_dist
from eucl_dist.gpu_dist import dist as gdist
%cd ..
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful!